# Is there any possibilities to send a sql-query by BigQueryClient API in C++?

Tags: c++, google-bigquery

I try to use BigQueryClient C++ API in my project. And I can't understand how it possible to send query to my BigQuery table using that client API?

I have already successfully connected to my google BigQuery project, create client and session. But I couldn't find no methods allows me send my queries...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.